# C# Decompress an Android Backup (adb) file

Tags: c#, android, adb, archive, zlib

I'm trying to decompress an Android adb file using the [Deflate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) algorithm. I've tried both DotNetZips Ionic Zlib as well as Microsofts built-in [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx) introduced in Net 4.5 but both of them result in a corrupted archive. They both have the exact same file size, but the hashes don't match up between the corrupt and good archives.

I'm using the following code to decompress.

```cs
byte[] app = File.ReadAllBytes(tb_keyOutDir.Text + "\\app_stripped.ab");
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(app);

//skip first two bytes to avoid invalid block length error
ms.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);

DeflateStream deflate = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);
string dec = new StreamReader(deflate, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd();

File.WriteAllText(tb_keyOutDir.Text + "\\app.tar", dec);
```

I can decompress it via CygWin with OpenSSL and it's decompressing it properly so I know my files aren't corrupted or anything.

```
cat app_stripped.ab | openssl zlib -d > app.tar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Ionic library

try use this method to decompress :

```
    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip) {
        using (var stream = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
            const int size = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream()) {
                int count = 0;
                do {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if (count > 0) {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

and when you want call :

```
    byte[] app = Decompress(File.ReadAllBytes(tb_keyOutDir.Text + "\\app_stripped.ab"));
    File.WriteAllBytes(tb_keyOutDir.Text + "\\app.tar", app);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I've edited your answer slightly since we're writing out bytes now instead of text.