# Decompress file using zlib - stuck at 256kb limit

Tags: c#, zlib, compression

I hope someone here will be able to help me out with this.
What I'm trying to do is decompress a zlib compressed file in C# using [ZlibNet](https://zlibnet.codeplex.com/). (I've also tried [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) and [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/))

The problem that I'm having is that it'll decompress only the first 256kb, or rather the first 262144 bytes.
Here's my Decompress method, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382485/c-sharp-decompress-an-android-backup-adb-file):

```
public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
    {
        using (var stream = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var outStream = new MemoryStream();
            const int size = 999999; //Playing around with various sizes didn't help
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

            int read;
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0)
            {
                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                read = 0;
            }

            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Basically, the int (read) gets set to 262144 on the first time the while loop executes, it writes, and then the next pass of the while loop, read gets said to 0, thus making the loop exit and the function return the outStream as an array. (Even though there are still bytes left to be read!)

Thanks in advance to anyone who could help with this!

Comment: Have you tried; removing `read = 0;` or setting buffer to like 10 bytes?

Comment: I have, but the result stays the same-- with the resulting file only being 262144 bytes big.

Comment: and you are sure that the gzip array is correct?

Comment: I looked at the loaded data in debug mode and it seemed to all be there-- this function also works flawlessly for any files smaller than 262144 bytes.

Comment: Do this `var gzipStream = new MemoryStream(gzip);` and use it in your ZlibStream. At the end of your method check `gzipStream.Position == gzip.length`

Comment: Tried your suggestion-- learned that for some reason the resulting gzipStream was 16384 as buffersize but the basestream does have a length of 6828054.

Comment: What is your expected output in bytes?

Comment: Maybe the uncompressed data is, in fact, 262144 bytes long.

Comment: The uncompressed file is 6943368 bytes in total. I've tried it on several compressed files and if their size is > 256Kb, it always results in it just outputting the first 256Kb

Comment: what is the `gzipStream.Position` and `gzip.length` _

Comment: The gzipStream.Position is 147456 and gzip.Length = 6828054, which leads me to believe that something is going wrong in the stream.Read, which would be weird considering it's a library I've seen recommended on here so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: and it is a deflate stream, not a zip file in your `byte[] gzip`?

Comment: well, it is late night for me. I would try two things; first find another deflatestream to test with, and if that also failes you must look closer to you gzip byte array.

Comment: The byte[] gzip array that gets passed to the Decompress function is the result of File.ReadAllBytes(fileName), if that's what you're asking. The actual file itself is just a file that got compressed by zlib in python. Thanks for staying up to try to help me, good night!

Comment: Have you tried decompressing the file back in Python, to make sure that it was compressed correctly?

Comment: @MarkAdler Sorry for the late reply, but yes, I've tried decompressing it using python and it can decompress it normally. Hence why I'm so confused as to why it's breaking on the C# side. Maybe the library is to blame? I know the standard DeflateStream doesn't work properly, but I'll have to look into other libraries.

Comment: I don't know anything about C# and .NET, but I hear good things about [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), which supports the zlib format.

Comment: That's the one I've been using, I've also tried SharpZipLib, which has the same issue for some reason? The latter just decompresses 262144 bytes (0x40000) and then fills with 0's. Very strange

Comment: Found the solution by looking at the data closely. Posted some details about it in my answer @MarkAdler . Thanks for your help in trying to solve this issue, and thanks for your initial work on the zlib library, the (tech) world wouldn't be the same without you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further inspection of the originally packed data, it turns out that the script responsible for (de)compressing the data in the original application would split the zlib stream of a file into chunks of 262144 bytes each.

This is why the various libraries I tested always stopped at 262144 bytes-- it was the end of the zlib stream, but not the end of the file it was supposed to extract. (Each zlib stream was also seperated by a 32-bit unsigned int that indicated the amount of bytes the next zlib stream would contain)

My only guess is that they did this so that if they had a very large file, they wouldn't need to load all of it into memory for decompression. (But that's just a guess.)